# How to extract common.css from .less with webpack?

Tags: less, webpack

I have some entries with their own .less styles
I want to extract common css into common.css

```
entry: {
    index: ['./client/js/index.js'],
    login: ['./client/js/login.js']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        ....
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')},
        {test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!less')}
        ....
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        minChunks: 2,
        name: 'common'
    })
]
```

but I cant manage to generate common.css if I use .less files

If I use .css files - common.css is generated!

How can I get common.css from .less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your webpack.optimize.CommonChunkPlugin settings should be "commons", "commons.js", like:

```
// ...
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("commons", "commons.js"),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
    ]
}
```